# AngularJs $resource use of isArray for both request and response

Tags: rest, angularjs, angular-resource

Not sure if this is a stupid question or not, maybe I'm missing something. When customizing methods on `$resource` I can use `isArray` to specify if *the resource* is an array or not. The problem is that `isArray` is used, for example with `POST`, to check both the shape of the request body *and* of the response. This means that I cannot have, for example, a `POST` where I need an array of anything (i.e. a set of operations to add to a batch task) in my request and I send a single object as a response (the batch task itself).

This is not a coding problem, I can work around this, it's more a design question: why do response and request have to have the same shape? I do not think that's stated anywhere around how to build REST services, they might usually have the same shape but they do not have to. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same "dilemma": I'm calling a REST service that receives an array using POST, so I have to set the `isArray` property to `true` in my `$resource.save()` function, but the service doesn't return back an array but a single object, so I'm receiving this error from AngularJs: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object It's not a blocking error, since the POST call is effective and the object is actually modified in the server, but it's an annoying error to have logged in the console, and I think your point is v

Comment: Yeah, to me it would make sense to separate the two. I don't see much action here on SO about this issue, maybe I'll open it on Github :)