# Object #<Resource> has no method 'push'

Tags: node.js, rest, angularjs, express, angular-resource

At first I had this, but got error `Expected response to contain an object but got an array`:

```
angular.module('homeModule').factory("TodosFactory", ['$resource', function ($resource) {
return $resource('/api/todos/:todoId', {
    todoId: '@_id'
});
}]);
```

So I changed to this:

```
angular.module('homeModule').factory("TodosFactory", ['$resource', function ($resource) {
return $resource('/api/todos/:todoId', {
    todoId: '@_id'
}, {'save': {method: 'POST', isArray:true}}); // this line is added
}]);
```

I am saving an item to database, and returning list of objects as a result. An JSON array is returned, but I get this error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `isArray` property is for both the request and the response. See [AngularJs $resource use of isArray for both request and response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234707/angularjs-resource-use-of-isarray-for-both-request-and-response).

It's getting an error because the request is not an array. You could wrap it in an array, and then pull it out server side.

Comment: Ok, possibly will solve the problem, but I already wrote the code,  so that that the item that is added to database, will be returned, not all the elements, so it will respect the REST architecture.